# Load a view that is previously loaded in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I have been searching around about this problem, but haven't got any answer yet. My problem is: I have a push button that when clicked will push to another view.

Here is how I push it:

```
ViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]
                      instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main_View"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

The ViewController vc is the view that I pushed. So in the new view, there is a Back button that can drop the current view and comeback to the old view. When I click the push button, the vc been load again from allover.

How can I make the instance of vc stay in memory, so when I go back to old view and come to vc again, it doesn't need to reload again?
I guess it is something related to navigationController stack, but don't know how to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep a ViewController instance as property in your first ViewController

```
@property (strong,nonatomic)ViewController * vc;
```

Then when push it,check if it is in memory

```
 if (self.vc == nil) {
    self.vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]
                                 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main_View"];
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a UINavigationController? If so, can call the following line of code in you back button 'IBAction':

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you really need to keep a instance of the view controller, do what Leo suggested.